# ROS time starts at 90

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04, using Gazebo as virtualizer and a Turtlebot.
So far, with every simulation I ran, I used the so-called `turtlebot_house.world` that came with installing the [ROBOTIS Turtlebot3 simulations](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations) package.
When I use that world, ROS time correctely starts at 0.00 secs.
Recently, I defined my own world using the Gazebo world editor tool as described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7McYSJFAqlU). When I launch a simulation in my world, ROS time starts at approx 90.00 secs: I can see this in the *stdout* shell and also getting the time inside my scripts.

I have no clue in what's wrong nor what to do to provide further details. The same issue also happens across PCs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341585/ros-time-starts-at-90/) by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2020-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the solution myself: gotta say it's definetly awkward, but for some reason my exported world had these four parameters:

```
<sim_time>92 36000000</sim_time>
<real_time>92 561712388</real_time>
<wall_time>1578849264 106447901</wall_time>
<iterations>92036</iterations>
```

I just commented them out and the time correctely starts at 0.00

---

Originally posted by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) with karma: 83 on 2020-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0